# Trying to get a list of Facebook IDs for those who have checked into a place

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to determine if it is possible to get a list of Facebook users and IDs (via JSON I assume) that have checked in to a place/page.

Is this even possible? Do you need an access token from each user account to access this information? I found Facebook's documentation to be less than helpful...any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the [FQL `checkin` table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/) but at most (based on the permissions granted) you'll get the user's & her friends' checkins.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that was the limitation.